# window.devicePixelRatio change listener

Tags: javascript, retina

`window.devicePixelRatio` will return 1 or 2 depending on if I'm using my retina monitor or standard. If I drag the window between the two monitors, this property will change. Is there a way I can have a listener fire when the change occurs?

Comment: I don't have two monitors to test this but I think the `resize` event will be fired when `window.devicePixelRatio` updates.

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't fire.

Comment: There is a good example at developer.mozilla.org [Example 2: Monitoring screen resolution or zoom level changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio).

Comment: @user2570380 You don't need two monitors to test this. Just open e.g. Chrome DevTools → Toggle device toolbar (phone/tablet icon at the top left of DevTools) → Triple dot menu → Add device pixel ratio, then change the DPR at will. Note that I use Chrome 81 as of writing.

Comment: @MichaelJohansen: It doesn't trigger for me at all (Windows), it also seems to be buggy currently, see this issue on the Chromium tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1294293

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took the IMO best answer (by @Neil) and made it a bit more human-readable:

```
function listenOnDevicePixelRatio() {
  function onChange() {
    console.log("devicePixelRatio changed: " + window.devicePixelRatio);
    listenOnDevicePixelRatio();
  }
  matchMedia(
    `(resolution: ${window.devicePixelRatio}dppx)`
  ).addEventListener("change", onChange, { once: true });
}
listenOnDevicePixelRatio();
```

No fixed boundary or variables needed.

Comment: This approach also matches the documentation in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#monitoring_screen_resolution_or_zoom_level_changes

Answer (score 15):

You can listen to a media query with `matchMedia` that will tell you when the devicePixelRatio goes past a certain barrier (unfortunately not for arbitrary scale changes).

e.g:

```
window.matchMedia('screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)')
    .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      if (e.matches) {
        /* devicePixelRatio >= 2 */
      } else {
        /* devicePixelRatio < 2 */
      }
    });
```

The listener will be called when you drag a window between monitors, and when plugging in or unplugging an external non-retina monitor (if it causes the window to move from a retina to non-retina screen or vice-versa).

`window.matchMedia` is supported in IE10+, and [all other modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia).

References: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123694, [MDN on `min-resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#resolution)

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to reflect the new method.

Comment: This is much worse than the other answers, because it only allows for fixed boundaries

Comment: @James could you delete your comment, because it relates to an old version of the answer

Answer (score 12):

Most (or all?) answers on the internet only detect a specific change. Typically they detect whether the value is 2 or something else.

The issue probably lies in the MediaQuery, because they only allow checking for specific hardcoded values.

With some programming, it's possible to dynamically create a media query, which checks for a change of the current value.

```
let remove = null;

const updatePixelRatio = () => {
  if(remove != null) {
      remove();
  }
  let mqString = `(resolution: ${window.devicePixelRatio}dppx)`;
  let media = matchMedia(mqString);
  media.addListener(updatePixelRatio);
  remove = function() {media.removeListener(updatePixelRatio)};

  console.log("devicePixelRatio: " + window.devicePixelRatio);
}
updatePixelRatio();
```

Comment: Smart, but isn't this repeatedly creating new `MediaQueryList`s that just remain out here?

Comment: That's a good point. It probably doesn't causes a leak, because I remove the listener, and this seems to be the only way to dispose it. But it's dependent on how the browser have implemented this feature.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#monitoring_screen_resolution_or_zoom_level_changes

Comment: Now, the MDN page is correct. :)
When answering the question, I did create a ticket.
https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/4478
They had fixed it about a year ago.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @florian-kirmaier this is exactly what I was looking for and if you pass in the option `{once: true}` in the event listener there is no need to manually keep track and remove the event listener.

```
(function updatePixelRatio(){
matchMedia(`(resolution: ${window.devicePixelRatio}dppx)`)
.addEventListener('change', updatePixelRatio, {once: true});
console.log("devicePixelRatio: " + window.devicePixelRatio);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this one, so that I can provide a callback, and for the callback not to fire initially but only on changes, and to be able to stop it when no longer needed:

```js
function onPixelRatioChange(cb) {
    let mediaQuery
    const listenerOptions = { once: true }
    let firstRun = true

    function onChange() {
        if (firstRun) firstRun = false
        else cb()

        mediaQuery = matchMedia(`(resolution: ${devicePixelRatio}dppx)`)
        mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', onChange, listenerOptions)
    }

    onChange()

    return function unlisten() {
        mediaQuery.removeEventListener('change', onChange, listenerOptions)
    }
}

// Then use it like this:

const unlisten = onPixelRatioChange(() => {
    console.log('pixel ratio changed:', devicePixelRatio)
})

// later, stop listening if desired:
unlisten()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typescript object version of @Florian's answer

```js
export default class DevicePixelRatioObserver {
    mediaQueryList: MediaQueryList | null = null

    constructor(readonly onDevicePixelRatioChanged: () => void) {
        this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this)
        this.createMediaQueryList()
    }

    createMediaQueryList() {
        this.removeMediaQueryList()
        let mqString = `(resolution: ${window.devicePixelRatio}dppx)`;

        this.mediaQueryList = matchMedia(mqString);
        this.mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', this._onChange)
    }
    removeMediaQueryList() {
        this.mediaQueryList?.removeEventListener('change', this._onChange)
        this.mediaQueryList = null
    }
    _onChange(event: MediaQueryListEvent) {
        this.onDevicePixelRatioChanged()
        this.createMediaQueryList()
    }
    destroy() {
        this.removeMediaQueryList()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that will watch pixel ratio changes and will return a 'stop watching' function:

It also allows passing custom 'targetWindow' if you work with multi window setup.

```
function watchDevicePixelRatio(callback: (ratio: number) => void, targetWindow: Window = window) {
  const media = targetWindow.matchMedia(`(resolution: ${targetWindow.devicePixelRatio}dppx)`);

  function handleChange() {
    callback(targetWindow.devicePixelRatio);
  }

  media.addEventListener("change", handleChange);

  return function stopWatching() {
    media.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
  };
}
```