# Does devicePixelRatio change when the browser window is dragged between monitors?

Tags: javascript, retina-display

With a retina Macbook Pro, it's possible to plug in an external monitor and you drag a browser window between the retina screen and the other, normal-DPI display.

Does this cause `window.devicePixelRatio` to dynamically change? And if so, is there any event I can monitor for when this happens?

I don't have one in front of me to test. I need to know because I might need to re-draw a canvas if it changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the devicePixelRatio changes, and you can detect it with `matchMedia`.

I think that you should have a look at this topic that give a more detailled answer for detect the change:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29653772/3914736

Comment: Note that if you set `devicePixelRatio` with JavaScript (e.g. open your console and type `devicePixelRatio = 1`) it appears to be fixed to that value and does not change to match the new display.

Comment: @ericsoco To you know how to re-set it to a dynamic value, so that it gets updated again?